# How should I wire a subpanel for my hot tub?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, usa

I’m installing a used 240v 48amp hot tub which has 4 wires (black, red, white, and green). My home panel has the neutral and grounds all tied together. Also I’ll have to install a sub panel as there are no spare locations to add more.

How should I wire it? What do I do with the neutral? Also the tub states I need a ground fault interrupt. I’m go with low voltage wiring but that’s where it stops.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking for a full tutorial on subpanels? That's a bit broad for this Q&A site and it's all been covered well already. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Do some searching and reading, then revise to ask something more specific. Be sure to provide details of your wire path, etc.

Comment: You probably want to do a load calculation for your panel first.  50 extra amps on a full panel can be iffy.  It does depend on your panel use.  Neutral and ground can be connected/bonded together only in the main panel.  Sub panels they need to be separate.  240v hurts a lot more than low voltage, if not comfortable or you think you do not have the knowledge to do it right, an electrician is cheaper than a coffin.

Comment: i suggest you invite a licensed electrician to give you a quote for that job. During their visit you are free to ask for clarifications (within reason, you didn't hire them to teach you). Perhaps the cost will not be that bad, too

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing panel please?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple questions embedded here, each worthy of discussion on its own. Maybe the best way to answer is to give enough high-level information to spur you into finding or asking additional, more focused questions.

This question hasn't indicated a specific geography, but I inferred (and added a tag!) that you're looking for advice specific to USA.

#### Subpanel / breaker locations

The fact there are no open slots in your panel does not *necessarily* mean it cannot hold any more circuits. Some brands of panels support "tandem" and "quad" breakers to increase the density of circuits. Some panels allow these breakers only in certain positions. You'd have to check the labeling on your specific panel to learn where these are allowed, if at all.

A subpanel is a fine direction to go too. You might do well to determine what is the highest-amperage yet affordable breaker supported by your panel and choose that as the breaker for the subpanel feeder. A breaker of 70 amps should be reasonably-priced, and 100 or even 150 amps may also be. Some lines suddenly get very expensive for a 200 amp branch breaker though (for example).

A subpanel will be wired with 4 wires: two hot legs, neutral, and ground. Yes, in the main panel it's likely that neutral and ground both land on the same bus bar, but still you must have both conductors.

#### Neutral

You'll need to install separate conductors for both neutral and ground to the hot tub. In a main panel they'll likely land on the same bus bar, but in a sub panel, they'll land on separate bus bars. Either way they both have to be there.

#### Ampacity

If the tub requires 48 amps then it probably needs a 60 amp circuit. Continuous loads are allowed to use only 80% of the circuit's ampacity, and 60 amps times 80% equals 48 amps.

Have a look at the question [there](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/271338/45928) for a little more discussion on choosing appropriate branch breaker, wiring, and disconnect.

Comment: And you could even go up a bit on the subpanel size so. you can power other stuff out of there in the future.  In fact, going up on feeder size will save you money, since 2-2-2-4 aluminum is proven safe as a heavy feeder, and it's dirt cheap compared to 60A copper wire.  #2 will fit on any breaker 70A or larger (many 60A breakers as well, depending on panel model).